# HTML input direction rtl

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a calculator app, and on my display section where you can see the entered number I'm using HTML input type text. I changed the direction to RTL, but now when I enter the first number, it is not possible to see the full number, because the number is in kind of italic font.

I'm trying to push the number to the left to make some kind of padding,  but no success. Here is a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: try `text-align:right`

Comment: Add your current relevant code.

Comment: Do you just show CSS and HTML of this element so that proper answer could be suggested

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you understand what's required in a question at SO.

Comment: Incomplete question

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  direction:rtl;
  padding:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <i>777</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input{
  text-align:right;
  font-style: italic;  
}
```

```html
<input type='text' value='777' readonly>
```

use `text-align:right;`

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="text"] {
   text-align: right;
   padding-right: 14px;
   font-style: italic;
}
```